# MooTools binding/keeping class scope in methods and inner functions

Tags: javascript, scope, mootools

I'm trying to use Mootools to add a button to a page dynamically. It all works fine, except the `addEvent` in the `addButton` function. I get an error saying that "Property 'sayHi' of object javascript:void(0); is not a function".

I assume this is due to my scope and that I somehow must bind the addButton function back to the global "this"? Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
var myClass = new Class({
    initialize: function(){
        this.sayHi();
    },

    sayHi: function(){
        alert('Hello World!');
    },

    addButton: function(){
        this.hiButton = new Element('a', {
            id: 'sayhi',
            html: 'Hi!',
            href: 'javascript:void(0);',
            events: {
                click: function(){
                    this.sayHi();
                }
            }
        }).inject($('myDiv'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your click handler, the `this` value is no longer the original object, but rather the button that was clicked on.

There might be a MooTools-specific way to address this, but wrapping this object creation in a function would be a simple, native way to solve this:

```
function getMyClass(){
   var self = new Class({
       initialize: function(){
           this.sayHi();
       },

       sayHi: function(){
           alert('Hello World!');
       },

       addButton: function(){
           this.hiButton = new Element('a', {
               id: 'sayhi',
               html: 'Hi!',
               href: 'javascript:void(0);',
               events: {
                   click: function(){
                       self.sayHi();
                   }
               }
          }).inject($('myDiv'));
       }
   });

   return self;
}
```

And then

```
var myClass = getMyClass();
```

**EDIT**

While the above is a fairly standard idiom in JavaScript, I'm told it doesn't play well with MooTools.  If that's the case, I would go with this (as another answer already mentions):

```
var myClass = new Class({
    initialize: function(){
        this.sayHi();
    },

    sayHi: function(){
        alert('Hello World!');
    },

    addButton: function(){
        var self;
        this.hiButton = new Element('a', {
            id: 'sayhi',
            html: 'Hi!',
            href: 'javascript:void(0);',
            events: {
                click: function(){
                    self.sayHi();
                }
            }
        }).inject($('myDiv'));
    }
});
```

Comment: this is an anti-pattern for mootools :) just a local `var self = this` or `fn(){}.bind(this)`

Comment: @DimitarChristoff - whoops.  Is dzejkej's answer better in that respect?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this problem because when the `click` handler is executed `this` is representing the `anchor` element object and not to your `myClass`.

Change the `addButton` to:

```
addButton: function(){
    var that = this;
    this.hiButton = new Element('a', {
        id: 'sayhi',
        html: 'Hi!',
        href: 'javascript:void(0);',
        events: {
            click: function(){
                that.sayHi();
            }
        }
    }).inject($('myDiv'));
}
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/oripus/edit#preview)** is the running example. Switch to Code view to view source.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way of handling this and is in many mootools more plugins is as follows:

```
var myClass = new Class({
    initialize: function(){
        this.sayHi();
    },

    sayHi: function(){
        alert('Hello World!');
    },

    addButton: function(){
        var self = this;
        this.hiButton = new Element('a', {
            id: 'sayhi',
            html: 'Hi!',
            href: 'javascript:void(0);',
            events: {
                click: function(){
                    self.sayHi();
                }
            }
        }).inject($('myDiv'));
    }
});
```

You can see it is very similiar to Adam Rackis solution but you do not need to wrap your class with a function call.

IMHO it keeps the code a bit cleaner/maintanable/mooish!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think it is *very* similar to my solution ;).

Comment: +1 for this as the mootools way is via `self` reference. not `that` or `_this`. the only other acceptable solution is via `.bind(this)` on the click function - though it's at a higher cost. by *acceptable*, I mean recommended by virtue of the framework itself and best practices/guides for sharing code and plugins.

Comment: another way is: `click: this.sayHi.bind(this)` - http://alpha.jsfiddle.net/CUJc3/

Answer (score 1):

Omg, what about bind? Doing `var self = this;` is just wrong. You can do something like this:

```
var myClass = new Class({
initialize: function(){
    this.sayHi();
},

sayHi: function(){
    alert('Hello World!');
},

addButton: function(){
    this.hiButton = new Element('a', {
        id: 'sayhi',
        html: 'Hi!',
        href: '#',
        events: {
            click: function(){
                this.sayHi();

                // this will stop event propagation
                return false;
            }.bind(this)
        }
    }).inject($('myDiv'));
}
});
```

You can check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9dkQa/)